# If a connected set $A$ is contained in a set $B$ that is contained in $\mathrm{cl}(A)$, then $B$ must be connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I don't follow the argument in line 3-4 that reads "Since $U$ is an open set containing $x$, there would be a point $y$ in $U \cap A$." If this line is indeed logical, could someone please elaborate on it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: $x \in \operatorname{cl}(A)$ means any neighborhood of $x$ (in particular $U$) contains at least one point of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s just the definition of closure: $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, so by definition every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A\setminus\{x\}$. (Here we could even just say that every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A$, since $x\notin A$.) $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so $U$ contains a point of $A\setminus\{x\}$. In particular, $A\cap U\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I have expanded the argument taking into account that x may be an isolated point, hopefully this is not unnecessary: "If x is in cl(A), then x is either an isolated or accumulation point of A. If the former, then we have both U and A containing x. If the latter, then every punctured open ball about x (and so every punctured neighbourhood of x) contains some y of A so that both U and A contain y."

Comment: @Ryan: You know that $x\in(\operatorname{click}A)\setminus A$, so $x$ cannot be an isolated point. // You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$x ∈ cl(A)$ is equivalent to “for every open $U$ containing $x$: $U ∩ A ≠ ∅$”.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it means the following :
If you have a $x\in cl(A)$, then there exist $x_n$ in A s.t. $x_n\rightarrow x$. Since U is an open set containing x, there exist $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset U$ right ? Then for some $N$ because $x_n\rightarrow x$, $x_n\in B(x,r)$ for $n>N$. Then you have $y$ (one $x_n$) in $U\cap A$

Comment: Note that the claim holds for any topological space, you don't need a metric to prove it.

Comment: Sure, I agree that your answers and Brian's are faster and cleaner, but I guess that if the author asks, it is probably because he didn't had the intuition (geometric or topologic). I just explained how I see your claims in a metric space. For me it is just more readable (but maybe it's only for me!)